# Is 'Reckon' Used Correctly in this Context?

Tags: word-usage

Is 'Reckon' Used Correctly in this Context: "Everyone reckons him to be the killer" 
and what does 'reckon' imply in that sentence?

Comment: What do you find in the dictionary, to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is a little confusing because it is using a rural dialect rather than standard English.

The word reckon (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reckon) is used in rural areas throughout the US to describe the process of drawing a conclusion through thoughtful reflection, as opposed to drawing a conclusion through hard facts or evidence.  When you use reckon, you imply that your conclusion is just a best guess.  This suits the relaxed and informal attitude associated with the rural dialect.

Example:
"What time will your brother get here?"  "I reckon about 8."

Therefore, the sentence you shared is correct, if non-standard. You could substitute "assumes" for "reckons" and the sentence has the same meaning.  The implication is that the speaker is from a rural area (or otherwise affecting a "country" accent) and that everyone shares the same opinion about the killer.  It also allows that everyone could be mistaken, since the speaker did not say that everyone *knows* he is the killer - just that they reckon it so.